# How to stub all condition methods in ruby's state_machine for testing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, state-machine, stubbing

I am using `state_machine` with rails to handle state on some active record models and testing them with rspec and factory girl. I also have a serialized array property called `state_path` that keeps track of the state history.

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :state_path, Array

  def initialize(*)
    super
    state_path << state_name
  end

  state_machine :state, :initial => :draft do
    after_transition do |project, transition|
      project.state_path << transition.to_name
    end

    event :do_work do
      transition :draft => :complete, :if => :tps_has_cover_page?
    end

    state :draft do
      # ...
    end

    state :complete do
      # ...
    end
  end

  private
    def tps_has_cover_page?
      # ...
    end
end
```

Now, to test that the `after_transition` hook is properly populating the `state_path` property, I stub out the `tps_has_cover_page?` transition condition method, because I don't care about that functionality in this test, and also it is integrated with other models (tps report model perhaps?)

```
it "should store the state path" do
  allow_any_instance_of(Project).to receive(:tps_has_cover_page?).and_return(true)

  project = create(:project)
  project.do_work

  expect(project.state_path).to eq([:draft, :complete])
end
```

However, the transition condition method name could change, or more conditions could be added, which I'm not really concerned with in this test (obviously, since I'm stubbing it).

**Question:** is there a way to dynamically collect all of the transition condition methods on a state machine? To then be able to build a macro that stubs out all of the condition methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
transition_conditions = state_machine.events.map(&:branches).flatten.flat_map(&:if_condition)
```

Comment: I have to flatten the branches before I can do the final flat map because the branches themselves are wrapped in arrays. `Project.state_machine.events.map(&:branches).flatten.flat_map(&:if_condition)` otherwise works great! Thanks for the answer, can you confirm the flatten? I'll accept answer if so.

Comment: running state_machine 1.2.0 btw

Comment: also for others referencing this there are also `:unless_conditions` inside the branches if you need those too